# How to scrape/get comments from facebook live stream or post?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I want to scrape facebook comments from fb live or post,..is there any way to get this? If anyone know please help me.

I am using this but it does not working.

as it does not give any errors. But is does not retrieve any comments.

Code:

```
import time
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import sys
 
usr = ""
pwd = ""
 
url1 = "https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=100"
# url = sys.argv[1]
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/Typewritersvoice/photos/a.618454505026995/1619833381555764/'

# To block the notifications
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver')
    
# time.sleep(5)
driver.get(url1)
 
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email' or @name='email']")
email.send_keys(usr)
print("email entered...")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']")
password.send_keys(pwd)
print("Password entered...")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='loginbutton']")
button.click()
print("button clicked...")

time.sleep(5)
print("login Successfully...")
driver.get(url)

print("Streaming URL entered...")

comments = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.UFICommentBody span')

print("Comment found " +str(len(comments)))

for x in range(len(comments)): 
    print (comments[x].text)
```

OutPut:

```
email entered...
Password entered...
button clicked...
login Successfully...
Streaming URL entered...
Comment found 0
```

as it does not give any errors. But is does not retrieve any comments.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, so they probably make it extra-hard for you to get data by scraping.

Comment: then how can I get comments from facebook live or post?

Comment: by checking out the api docs and using the api only - if there is an endpoint for it

Answer (score 0):

You better use xpath rather than css.selector, But in the new version of facebook its extremely hard to find the xpath, but still possible. There is no unique ID in source code.

//div[@aria-posinset]//div[contains(@aria-label,'Comment by')]//a/span/span[@dir='auto']

For example, this xpath is for group-post-username of comment writer. Don't forget its for only new version of facebook

Comment: Thank you. But I need comments from facebook live? how can I get that, without API?